# EXC_BAD_ACCESS and terminated due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, xcode-instruments, memory-pressure

My app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message. I enabled NSZombie objects, however that caused a 'terminated due to memory pressure' error - even in debug mode.

I also saw the video http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/, but I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 and it doesn't have any option within Instruments as indicated in the video to enable Zombies from there.

I have enabled exception breakpoints.

Is there any other way to deal with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, or anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace?

Comment: To get memory problems with ARC is very rare. So you should know where you use so much memory within one method that could cause this problem.I never needed NSZombie since ARC is out.

Comment: You are allocating too much memory somewhere in your code. There is a tool for that in Instruments to track memory allocations over time.

Comment: Kerni is correct, while you in debug mode (without NSZombie) pay attention to your memory usage its probably get really big in that place you allocating too much memory.